# Jenkins slave failing to write to jarCache

Tags: java, linux, windows, jenkins, master-slave

Background info: I have a Kubernetes Cluster with 3 linux nodes and 1 windows node. Everything from the jenkins master to agents is in a container or pod controlled by Kubernetes.

I trying to connect a Windows agent(in a container) to a Linux master(also in a container), and I am running into problems when truing to connect the slave to the master using the hudson.remoting.jnlp.

My "java -version" returns :
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)

My Jenkins master version is 2.126 and its java version is:
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-1~deb9u1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

I'm using the remoting-3.15.jar with the command "java -cp C:\slave2.jar hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main -headless -tunnel :50000 -url http://:8080 -workDir C:\jenkins\agents  windows-jnlp-c3c71"

here is the error from that command:

```
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:16 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up slave: windows-jnlp-c3c71
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:16 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:16 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using C:\jenkins\agents\remoting as a remoting work directory
Both error and output logs will be printed to C:\jenkins\agents\remoting
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:16 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://172.31.50.121:8080]
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:16 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, CLI2-connect, JNLP-connect, Ping, CLI-connect, JNLP2-connect]
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:16 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: 172.31.50.121
  Agent port:    50000
  Identity:      fc:9f:20:0d:43:fa:ba:57:31:b0:f8:d5:8c:b4:14:cb
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:16 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:16 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to 172.31.50.121:50000
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:16 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:18 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: fc:9f:20:0d:43:fa:ba:57:31:b0:f8:d5:8c:b4:14:cb
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:18 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:20 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
Aug 15, 2018 8:06:20 PM hudson.remoting.JarCacheSupport$1 run
WARNING: Failed to resolve a jar a8eac714f1e2fe381c068493abefe27b
java.io.IOException: Failed to write to C:\jenkins\agents\remoting\jarCache\A8\EAC714F1E2FE381C068493ABEFE27B.jar
        at hudson.remoting.FileSystemJarCache.retrieve(FileSystemJarCache.java:142)
        at hudson.remoting.JarCacheSupport$1.run(JarCacheSupport.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Backing channel 'JNLP4-connect connection to 172.31.50.121/172.31.50.121:50000' is disconnected.
        at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.channelOrFail(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:192)
        at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:257)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.writeJarTo(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.FileSystemJarCache.retrieve(FileSystemJarCache.java:107)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1129)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:527)
        at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteBufferCommandTransport.processCommand(AbstractByteBufferCommandTransport.java:202)
        at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteBufferCommandTransport.receive(AbstractByteBufferCommandTransport.java:188)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onRead(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:186)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecv(ApplicationLayer.java:207)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecv(ProtocolStack.java:669)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processRead(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:369)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecv(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:117)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecv(ProtocolStack.java:669)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRead(NetworkLayer.java:136)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer.access$2200(BIONetworkLayer.java:48)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer$Reader.run(BIONetworkLayer.java:283)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:98)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: Command close created at
        at hudson.remoting.Command.<init>(Command.java:65)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.<init>(Channel.java:1265)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.<init>(Channel.java:1263)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1436)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1403)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.closeChannel(SlaveComputer.java:769)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.access$800(SlaveComputer.java:102)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$3.run(SlaveComputer.java:687)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


My pipeline error in jenkins is:

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \etc\hostname
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.FilePath$Read.invoke(FilePath.java:2010)
    at hudson.FilePath$Read.invoke(FilePath.java:2002)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3078)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:181)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:52)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at hudson.remoting.FastPipedInputStream.read(FastPipedInputStream.java:169)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2001)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1980)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1957)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1907)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:778)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:759)
    at hudson.FilePath.readToString(FilePath.java:2089)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.KubernetesNodeContext.getPodName(KubernetesNodeContext.java:42)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerStepExecution.start(ContainerStepExecution.java:91)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:8)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:138)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:569)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:322)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:320)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:568)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:223)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:456)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:455)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:221)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:366)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:365)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:220)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:404)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:403)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:219)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:494)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:493)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:239)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:304)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:303)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:217)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:520)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:200)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried matching the Java versions of master and slave, using the most recent remoting.jar file and changing protocol types. 
Any help or ideas would be apreciated

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few things that I would recommend changing:

1. Your launch command

`java -cp C:\slave2.jar hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main -headless -tunnel :50000 -url http://:8080 -workDir C:\jenkins\agents windows-jnlp-c3c71`

The first portion `java -cp C:\slave2.jar` says to look for a jar file at `C:\slave2.jar`.  But, you said your master is a Linux box.  If that is true then `C:\slave2.jar` won't exist.

2. `slave2.jar` is not the normal filename for the slave agent.  It's normally `agent.jar`.  So, it looks like a custom build perhaps.  In which case it might not have been built correctly.
3. The error, `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \etc\hostname`

That file should exist on a Linux server and not exist at that location on a Windows server.  So, something is searching in the wrong place for things.

I recommend making the following adjustments to connect your Windows slave to a Linux master:

On the `master` go to

```
Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security -> Agents
```

Verify that it is **enabled** and that it uses a fixed port and protocol 4.

Verify that the port is open on the Jenkins master's firewall.

Then go to:

```
Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> [YOUR_NODE] -> Configure -> Launch Method
```

Select `Launch agent via Java Webstart` and it will pretty much display the command you should use to which you can add your tunneling parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the help! sorry I should better clarified myself for your points 1 and 2.

Comment: I am running the command "java -cp C:\slave2.jar hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main -headless -tunnel :50000 -url http://:8080 -workDir C:\jenkins\agents windows-jnlp-c3c71" on the windows host. I also had a RUN command in the jnlp dockerfile that downloaded this file: https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/remoting/3.15/remoting-3.15.jar and renamed it slave2.jar at location C:\. So just to clarify C:\slave2 is just a renamed remoting-3.15.jar file and not a custom build.

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  No commands should be needed on the Windows slave.  The process is driven by the Linux master.  You don't even need the jar file on the Windows slave unless you plan on using the slave as a master at some point.  The most that you should need to do is to install the Windows slave plugin within Jenkins.  But, nothing should need to be done at the command line.

Comment: sorry, I'm confused I guess. The kubernetes plugin for linux agents sets up a pod with a jnlp container and software dependices container. By default the Jnlp container downloads a remoting.jar file and run the "java -cp ..." command, all on the linux agent, not the linux master. I was just trying to recreate that for the windows agents

Comment: Ahhhhhh.  That's a critically important piece of information that you didn't mention.  That explains why your command is so different.  Although, it doesn't explain why /etc/hostname isn't being found.  Could you update your question to contain the actual situation.  Namely, if your slaves are containers as opposed to VMs or if the master is a VM and the slave a container or if everything is running in containers manged by Kubernetes.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I edited my post to reduce confusion and state everthing is in containers. Yeah I was really thrown off by etc/hostname because it was running on a window agent, is the remoting.jar specificly only for linux environment?

Comment: Thanks.  I read your update and things are a lot more clear now.  The Jenkins master needs to have the agent.  The master uses the agent to talk to the slaves over TCP.  The Windows slave isn't connecting because the Jenkins command is being run on the slave.  The command needs to be run on the master.  So, the problem is that you have Kubernetes running the command on the slaves instead of on the master.  But, in that case none of the slaves should be connecting unless you have that step built into the container.  Are the Linux slaves connecting?  If so, how did you get them to connect?

Comment: The linux slaves are connecting, and the setup is automatic through Jenkins X. This means they connect by me just clicking run on a build, they automatically are provisioned, run the pipeline and get deleted. The actual setup of these container are through this dockerfile in this github: [link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave). The container runs a script called jenkins-slave [link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave/blob/master/jenkins-slave) which at the end runs the command "exec $JAVA_BIN $JAVA_OPTS $JNLP_PROTOCOL_OPTS -cp /usr/share/jenkins/slave.jar ...."

Comment: here is an image of the kubernetes pod setup in jenkins: [link](https://i.imgur.com/fJ1kCUu.png)

Comment: Your kubernetes pod only builds Linux Jenkins slaves.  That's why your Linux slaves connect.  But, the pod's not building a Windows Jenkins slave.  You need something like https://hub.docker.com/r/jonathank/jenkins-jnlp-slave-windows/ .  But, that's not going to work if your Kubernetes is running on Linux.   Unless you use https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/04/20/running-docker-windows-and-linux-containers-simultaneously  you can't get Linux  & Windows containers running together.  The best way to get Linux & Windows slaves running together is with VMs not containers.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! yes my 3 linux vms run the linux containers and my 1 windows vm runs my windows containers. I was able to connect the winodw's agent because of simple pipeline syntax, which is sort of weird. The incorrect pipeline had a section with: container ("jnlp"){  bat echo yo}, but if i removed the container it would work

Comment: pipeline {
  agent {
    label "jenkins-windows-jnlp"
  }
  stages {
    stage('Validate Environment') {
      steps {
        container('jnlp') {
            bat 'echo build'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
this gave the nofileexecption: /etc/hostname error

Comment: pipeline {
  agent {
    label "jenkins-windows-jnlp"
  }
  stages {
    stage('Validate Environment') {
      steps {
            bat 'echo build'
      }
    }
  }
}
was successful and had no errors, I don't know why but it is very weird that it is like this

Comment: Given that you aren't using https://hub.docker.com/r/jonathank/jenkins-jnlp-slave-windows/ to build the Windows Jenkins slave, the Windows container never gets built.  It looks like with **container** in the pipeline syntax, the Windows VM tries to build a Windows container using a Linux image and fails as expected.  This also explains the ***/etc/hostname*** error.  When you take **container** out, the Windows VM skips the container build and runs the agent command itself, which is what's mentioned in my original answer which is based on the Windows slave being a VM and not a container.

Comment: Check the kubernetes logs.  I don't think it will show a Windows container ever getting built.

Comment: My dockerfile and script is similar to https://hub.docker.com/r/jonathank/jenkins-jnlp-slave-windows/ because i was basing it off of [https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave). also apparently the windows container was created. IDK whats going on

Comment: Are you just testing that the containers get created?  Or are the containers supposed to be doing something?  If the containers are supposed to be doing something, check and verify that the windows container actually does what you think it's supposed to be doing.